Выбрать только первый результат из цикла
Пытаюсь получить цену из списка, но только из первой ячейки, мне выдаёт результат из всего списка:
price = [i2['price'] for i2 in data2['data'][hash_name]]

Вот сам список:
{
  "success": true,
  "currency": "RUB",
  "data": {
    "PP-Bizon | Night Riot (Field-Tested)": [
      {
        "id": 5449052677,
        "price": "552",
        "class": 5955420454,
        "instance": 188530139,
        "extra": {
          "seller_steam_level": 0,
          "float": "0.16221784055233",
          "asset": "37995651885",
          "percent_success": "95.00",
          "average_time": "103",
          "volume": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 5449068539,
        "price": "635",
        "class": 5956050212,
        "instance": 188530139,
        "extra": {
          "seller_steam_level": 0,
          "float": "0.1979790776968",
          "asset": "37994518926",
          "percent_success": "95.00",
          "average_time": "85",
          "volume": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 5449929203,
        "price": "635",
        "class": 5958632634,
        "instance": 188530139,
        "extra": {
          "seller_steam_level": 0,
          "float": "0.20205883681774",
          "asset": "38026967443",
          "percent_success": "95.00",
          "average_time": "113",
          "volume": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}



Для того чтобы получить значение ключа 'price' необязательно перебирать весь словарь. Достаточно указать номер элемента в списке и тогда вы получите нужное вам значение в этом элементе списка.
price = data2['data'][hash_name][0]['price']
print(price) # 552


Я был очень близок к результату)) Спасибо большое, всё сработало как надо :)
